# How to Create/Manage a WCF Project in a VS2013 App Using WPF anf MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm, visual-studio-2013

I have fiew question about the WCF Service Library. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 WPF and the MVVM Pattern.

So in my Solution I have multiple projects and 1 of em is the WCF Service Library. In my Library I have a Service for Users

my Questions are :

1. Is it Better to separate the WCF Service Library in an another Solution ?
2. Where should I create my UserModel ? (Right now it's in my User Project not the Service Library)
3. How should I reference my Service in my Projects
4. Where and How should I store my SQL DB Connection String, how should I wrap the sensitive data like the Password ?
5. Should my Services be placed on the Server ?

Also, If you have any good Tutorials for WPF MVVM WCF Services that would greatly help.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes: I would create a separate WCF application and run that in parrellel with your WPF app.
2. I'm not sure what a user model is.
3. You add a service reference to your exe or class library. In there, you specify the endpoint address.
4. Consider using Entity Framework as well.
5. Yes or a Windows Service

Comment: UserModel is my Model that defines a user using the MVVM pattern and thank for the answers